# I can connect to my web server with my internal IP, but not my external IP?

Tags: webserver

I have recently installed a webserver, and port 80 is open. I can connect with 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.0.50, but I can't with my external IP. So, why is this?

I use a router from Ubee.

Comment: Success: I can see your service on 68.202.xxx.xxx on port (80)
Your ISP is not blocking port 80

Comment: Are you still having this problem?

Comment: Yes, I am. I have not found a solution. I have added my internal into the DMZ host area, and still the same problem.
Advanced Gateway - DMZ Host (Exposed Host)
DMZ Address  192.168.0.50

Comment: Is this server connected to the internet through a router?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's an Ubee router.

Comment: See guntbert's answer. That's exactly what I was going to say ;-) You are going to need to forward port 80 on your router to the internal IP of the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are connecting via a router you will have to configure that router to "forward" packets to your server. How that can be done depends on the router, sometimes you will find the setting under *DMZ*, sometimes under *services*.

It will look like:

- external port (probably 80)
- internal host to forward it to (192.168.0.50)
- port on the destination to use (again 80)

Seth found a guide for your router: [Port Forwarding the Ubee U10C022-Ambit Router for Apache](http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Ubee/U10C022-Ambit/Apache.htm)

Comment: Here's a guide for an Ubee router and Apache: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Ubee/U10C022-Ambit/Apache.htm

Comment: @Chimerica I get "It works!" the default Apache message when it installed right.

Comment: I can not connect to it, and neither can my friend (who I'm setting up a cPanel for.) I get the same problem with :8080.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/2maPhvf.png

Comment: I can't just solo out 4 ports, as you see. I got 80, 2011, 2012, 25564 and 25565

Answer (score 1):

Along with gunbert's solution there may be another problem preventing you from accessing the server outside of your LAN.

Depending on where you live, certain ISPs prevent certain kind of external access to their customers. The most common of these would be port 80.

If port forwarding doesn't work, look online for what ports your ISP filters.